# Need help in picking solution and understanding when to add columns vs EAV

Tags: sql-server, database-design, eav

I've been working on the following problem for a long time and I can't decide between two solutions. While both would work to solve the problem, neither "feels" exactly right to me.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated. Also note that I'm not particularly great with DB design so any feedback is appreciated.

I have the following table:

**ProductYearDistrictCrop (+-2 million records)**

```
oid | productId | yearId | districId     | cropId | payDate     | 
1   | 1         | 1      | 1             |1       | 2018-01-01  |
2   | 1         | 1      | 1             |1       | 2018-02-01  |
3   | 2         | 1      | 1             |1       | 2018-03-01  |
4   | 2         | 1      | 1             |1       | 2018-04-01  |
```

Some background info on the table:

A record is created for each possible combination of Product - Year - District - Crop and there is a unique constraint on those Foreign Keys (the combination must be unique). I opted to use Oid as the PK instead of a Composite Key because Oid can then be used by other tables as a FK and I assumed a lookup on the Oid would be quicker than a composite key.

For each of these records, there are additional options that can be picked from. These options come from the below table

**Options (16 records)**

```
oid | description   | systemDefaultValue
1   | Option 1      | 0.5 
2   | Option 2      | 2.5
3   | Option 3      | 1.5
4   | Option 4      | 1.5
```

For each of these choices I need to store a custom value or just reuse the systemDefaultValue per record in **ProductYearDistrictCrop**

The two possible solutions I come up with are

**Solution A : Simple add each possible option as column to the table**

```
oid | productId | yearId | districId     | cropId | payDate     | Option1   | Option2   | 
1   | 1         | 1      | 1             |1       | 2018-01-01  | 0.5       | 2.5       |
2   | 1         | 1      | 1             |1       | 2018-02-01  | 0.5       | 2.5       |
3   | 2         | 1      | 1             |1       | 2018-03-01  | 0.5       | 2.5       |
4   | 2         | 1      | 1             |1       | 2018-04-01  | 0.5       | 2.5       |
```

Which means we'll end up with 16 extra columns in **ProductYearDistrictCrop** and of course, each time a new option is added to the system, I need to update this table as well. While this doesn't happen often, it can happen.

The other consideration is that there are other tables that will also follow a similar design so that means I would have to update several tables each time a new option is added.

**Solution B : Use what I think is an [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) approach for the options by creating a linking table**

**ProductYearDistrictCropOptionChoices**

```
ProductYearDistrictCrop  | optionId  | customValue |
1                        | 1         | 0.5         |
2                        | 2         | 1.5         |
3                        | 3         | 100         |
4                        | 4         | 25          |
```

In this scenario I end up with a +- 32 million records. The obvious upside is that no db changes are required each time a new option is added. Also I'm working with worst case scenario so it's not that each record from **ProductYearDistrictCrop** WILL have 16 records linked to it.

**My Feedback**

My gut feeling to pick **Solution A** and add the columns for each option. I can then do a single lookup when I need the data and get everything I need from that row or sets of rows.

The other reason I prefer **Solution A** is that to my understanding attributes should be columns in a database. It's just that another table is already storing those attributes as options to be used by the system when building UIs and providing hte user with default options and values.

I've been wrestling with this for a long time and would just like to get some external advice and insights. Also it would help to get more opinions as I would like to justify my choice with a stronger reasoning than "I feel this one is good and that one is icky"

Comment: Roughly what proportion of option values are non-default? That is, how exceptional is it for a given PYDC to have a non-default value for a given option?

Comment: So I modified this question to hide some of the additional complexity, but in reality of the 16 options there are 14 that will always use the system default value and 2 that will always use the custom value.

It is because 14 are "checkbox" options and 2 are "range" options to which the use will enter a custom value.

Comment: I think another variable to take into account is the likely-hood that there will be more than 16 options in the future.  How likely are you to need more than 16 options in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richard,

I really think this is a great question you have posed.  My answer got longer than I anticipated so in summary I have 3 possible solutions based on what you asked.  If I had to rank my preference I would do:

1. `EVA` table
2. Multiple Child Tables
3. Single "Extension" table

---

***EVA Approach***

Thanks to some insight from Jon the `EVA` is certainly a very viable approach with proper indexing using a `PIVOT`

For the sake of the example on the `PIVOT` (since I was not familiar with it) I created a simple `EAV` table.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    OptionID INT NOT NULL,
    [Value] INT NULL
)
```

I then populated it with 16 unique `ID`'s and each configured for 16 different `OptionID`'s.  The value is populated with the product of `ID` and `OptionID` If those two values are the same then no value was provided (If ID <= 6 a value of `NULL` was provided, else no row was added (so that we got examples for both a `NULL` value and a missing row)).

```
INSERT INTO @Table (ID, OptionID, Value)
VALUES (1, 1, NULL),
(1, 2, 2),
(1, 3, 3),
(1, 4, 4),
(1, 5, 5),
(1, 6, 6),
(1, 7, 7),
(1, 8, 8),
(1, 9, 9),
(1, 10, 10),
(1, 11, 11),
(1, 12, 12),
(1, 13, 13),
(1, 14, 14),
(1, 15, 15),
(1, 16, 16),
(2, 1, 2),
(2, 2, NULL),
(2, 3, 6),
(2, 4, 8),
(2, 5, 10),
(2, 6, 12),
(2, 7, 14),
(2, 8, 16),
(2, 9, 18),
(2, 10, 20),
(2, 11, 22),
(2, 12, 24),
(2, 13, 26),
(2, 14, 28),
(2, 15, 30),
(2, 16, 32),
(3, 1, 3),
(3, 2, 6),
(3, 3, NULL),
(3, 4, 12),
(3, 5, 15),
(3, 6, 18),
(3, 7, 21),
(3, 8, 24),
(3, 9, 27),
(3, 10, 30),
(3, 11, 33),
(3, 12, 36),
(3, 13, 39),
(3, 14, 42),
(3, 15, 45),
(3, 16, 48),
(4, 1, 4),
(4, 2, 8),
(4, 3, 12),
(4, 4, NULL),
(4, 5, 20),
(4, 6, 24),
(4, 7, 28),
(4, 8, 32),
(4, 9, 36),
(4, 10, 40),
(4, 11, 44),
(4, 12, 48),
(4, 13, 52),
(4, 14, 56),
(4, 15, 60),
(4, 16, 64),
(5, 1, 5),
(5, 2, 10),
(5, 3, 15),
(5, 4, 20),
(5, 5, NULL),
(5, 6, 30),
(5, 7, 35),
(5, 8, 40),
(5, 9, 45),
(5, 10, 50),
(5, 11, 55),
(5, 12, 60),
(5, 13, 65),
(5, 14, 70),
(5, 15, 75),
(5, 16, 80),
(6, 1, 6),
(6, 2, 12),
(6, 3, 18),
(6, 4, 24),
(6, 5, 30),
(6, 6, NULL),
(6, 7, 42),
(6, 8, 48),
(6, 9, 54),
(6, 10, 60),
(6, 11, 66),
(6, 12, 72),
(6, 13, 78),
(6, 14, 84),
(6, 15, 90),
(6, 16, 96),
(7, 1, 7),
(7, 2, 14),
(7, 3, 21),
(7, 4, 28),
(7, 5, 35),
(7, 6, 42),
--(7, 7, NULL),
(7, 8, 56),
(7, 9, 63),
(7, 10, 70),
(7, 11, 77),
(7, 12, 84),
(7, 13, 91),
(7, 14, 98),
(7, 15, 105),
(7, 16, 112),
(8, 1, 8),
(8, 2, 16),
(8, 3, 24),
(8, 4, 32),
(8, 5, 40),
(8, 6, 48),
(8, 7, 56),
--(8, 8, NULL),
(8, 9, 72),
(8, 10, 80),
(8, 11, 88),
(8, 12, 96),
(8, 13, 104),
(8, 14, 112),
(8, 15, 120),
(8, 16, 128),
(9, 1, 9),
(9, 2, 18),
(9, 3, 27),
(9, 4, 36),
(9, 5, 45),
(9, 6, 54),
(9, 7, 63),
(9, 8, 72),
--(9, 9, NULL),
(9, 10, 90),
(9, 11, 99),
(9, 12, 108),
(9, 13, 117),
(9, 14, 126),
(9, 15, 135),
(9, 16, 144),
(10, 1, 10),
(10, 2, 20),
(10, 3, 30),
(10, 4, 40),
(10, 5, 50),
(10, 6, 60),
(10, 7, 70),
(10, 8, 80),
(10, 9, 90),
--(10, 10, NULL),
(10, 11, 110),
(10, 12, 120),
(10, 13, 130),
(10, 14, 140),
(10, 15, 150),
(10, 16, 160),
(11, 1, 11),
(11, 2, 22),
(11, 3, 33),
(11, 4, 44),
(11, 5, 55),
(11, 6, 66),
(11, 7, 77),
(11, 8, 88),
(11, 9, 99),
(11, 10, 110),
--(11, 11, NULL),
(11, 12, 132),
(11, 13, 143),
(11, 14, 154),
(11, 15, 165),
(11, 16, 176),
(12, 1, 12),
(12, 2, 24),
(12, 3, 36),
(12, 4, 48),
(12, 5, 60),
(12, 6, 72),
(12, 7, 84),
(12, 8, 96),
(12, 9, 108),
(12, 10, 120),
(12, 11, 132),
--(12, 12, NULL),
(12, 13, 156),
(12, 14, 168),
(12, 15, 180),
(12, 16, 192),
(13, 1, 13),
(13, 2, 26),
(13, 3, 39),
(13, 4, 52),
(13, 5, 65),
(13, 6, 78),
(13, 7, 91),
(13, 8, 104),
(13, 9, 117),
(13, 10, 130),
(13, 11, 143),
(13, 12, 156),
--(13, 13, NULL),
(13, 14, 182),
(13, 15, 195),
(13, 16, 208),
(14, 1, 14),
(14, 2, 28),
(14, 3, 42),
(14, 4, 56),
(14, 5, 70),
(14, 6, 84),
(14, 7, 98),
(14, 8, 112),
(14, 9, 126),
(14, 10, 140),
(14, 11, 154),
(14, 12, 168),
(14, 13, 182),
--(14, 14, NULL),
(14, 15, 210),
(14, 16, 224),
(15, 1, 15),
(15, 2, 30),
(15, 3, 45),
(15, 4, 60),
(15, 5, 75),
(15, 6, 90),
(15, 7, 105),
(15, 8, 120),
(15, 9, 135),
(15, 10, 150),
(15, 11, 165),
(15, 12, 180),
(15, 13, 195),
(15, 14, 210),
--(15, 15, NULL),
(15, 16, 240),
(16, 1, 16),
(16, 2, 32),
(16, 3, 48),
(16, 4, 64),
(16, 5, 80),
(16, 6, 96),
(16, 7, 112),
(16, 8, 128),
(16, 9, 144),
(16, 10, 160),
(16, 11, 176),
(16, 12, 192),
(16, 13, 208),
(16, 14, 224),
(16, 15, 240)--,
--(16, 16, NULL)
```

The table can then be queried with a `PIVOT` command.  (As I understand it the `PIVOT` requires that we use an `Aggregate` function `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, etc.... If there is a constraint added so that the `ID-OptionID` combination is unique we shouldn't get any incorrect outputs.  I just arbitrarily chose `SUM`)

I am not familiar with how well the `PIVOT` function performs but it is a built-in function so I would imagine performance is pretty good.

```
SELECT ID, 
[1] AS Option1, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 1 Grouped By ID
[2] AS Option2, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 2 Grouped By ID
[3] AS Option3, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 3 Grouped By ID
[4] AS Option4, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 4 Grouped By ID
[5] AS Option5, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 5 Grouped By ID
[6] AS Option6, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 6 Grouped By ID
[7] AS Option7, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 7 Grouped By ID
[8] AS Option8, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 8 Grouped By ID
[9] AS Option9, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 9 Grouped By ID
[10] AS Option10, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 10 Grouped By ID
[11] AS Option11, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 11 Grouped By ID
[12] AS Option12, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 12 Grouped By ID
[13] AS Option13, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 13 Grouped By ID
[14] AS Option14, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 14 Grouped By ID
[15] AS Option15, --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 15 Grouped By ID
[16] AS Option16  --SUM([Value]) where OptionID = 16 Grouped By ID
FROM 
(
    SELECT ID, OptionID, [Value]
    FROM @Table
) UP
PIVOT (
        SUM([Value]) 
        FOR [OptionID] IN([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16]) --Values held in the OptionID column
    ) AS pvt
ORDER BY ID
```

This give you a strong blend of:

1. Easy of adding new options (all this code can be loaded up in a `VIEW` or `CTE` for easy of use.  When a new `Option` is added you would simply add an additional Column in the final select `[17] AS Option17` and Add `, [17]` in the `FOR [OptionID](...)` piece of the `PIVOT`).
2. Space savings since records can only be added if they differ than the default and that can be applied via a `CASE` statement.
3. `EAV` tables are really narrow, so as long as the table is indexed well performance should be really good.

***Extension Table Approach***

***When It Comes To The Additional Columns Approach*** most people's concern is that it isn't normalized out.  I hear a comment one time about "Normalize until it hurts. De-Normalize until it works".  (There is actually a [DBA Stack Exchange topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/when-should-you-denormalize/4625) which covered this idea about how far to go with `Normalization`).  With all that in mind if this is going to be a highly utilized part of the database than this may be a candidate where taking a slightly de-normalized design, for performance reasons may be what you want to do.

***I would not however recommend adding the columns onto your existing table.***  The wider the table is, the less data you can fit onto the same page which means that everything else using this table will take a performance degradation.  One way around that is creating an "Extension" `table` which doesn't do anything but hold these values.  You would simply `JOIN` to this one table to get all 16 options (whether they are always written, or the columns are `NULLABLE` and only hold have a value if it differs from the default).  When an additional `Option` is added, you would just add a new column to this table.

This table, space-wise would be really inefficient.  But we would be sacrificing that space, for `SELECT` query performance in both instances where `ProductYearDistrictCrop` is used without this new extension table and when `ProductYearDistrictCrop` is used in unison with it.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductYearDistrictCropOptions]
(
    [Oid] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [Option1] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, --Or Whatever the appropriate datatype is
    [Option2] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option3] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option4] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option5] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option6] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option7] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option8] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option9] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option10] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option11] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option12] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option13] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option14] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option15] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 
    [Option16] [Decimal(10,5)] NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductYearDistrictCropOptions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Oid] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductYearDistrictCropOptions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductYearDistrictCropOptions_ProductYearDistrictCrop] FOREIGN KEY([Oid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ProductYearDistrictCrop] ([Oid])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductYearDistrictCropOptions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductYearDistrictCropOptions_ProductYearDistrictCrop]
GO
```

***Multiple Child Table Approach***

***You can get around the poor space utilization with multiple `child tables`***

I was reading an [article](https://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Missing-info-without-nulls.pdf) the other day reference in a different [DBA Stack Exchange Question on NULLS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/why-shouldnt-we-allow-nulls/5227).  This Article suggested that multiple child tables holding values can be used to designate this.  Where each `option` has its own `child table` which holds this data. You would end up creating 16 version of something like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductYearDistrictCropOption1Values]
(
    [Oid] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [Decimal(10,5)] NOT NULL, --Or Whatever the appropriate datatype is

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductYearDistrictCropOption1Values] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Oid] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductYearDistrictCropOption1Values]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductYearDistrictCropOption1Values_ProductYearDistrictCrop] FOREIGN KEY([Oid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ProductYearDistrictCrop] ([Oid])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductYearDistrictCropOption1Values] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductYearDistrictCropOption1Values_ProductYearDistrictCrop]
```

You would then reference everything by using something like

```
DECLARE @Option1Default Decimal(10,5), --Or Whatever the appropriate datatype is
@Option2Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option3Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option4Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option5Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option6Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option7Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option8Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option9Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option10Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option11Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option12Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option13Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option14Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option15Default Decimal(10,5),
@Option16Default Decimal(10,5)

SET @Option1Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 1')
SET @Option2Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 2')
SET @Option3Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 3')
SET @Option4Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 4')
SET @Option5Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 5')
SET @Option6Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 6')
SET @Option7Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 7')
SET @Option8Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 8')
SET @Option9Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 9')
SET @Option10Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 10')
SET @Option11Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 11')
SET @Option12Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 12')
SET @Option13Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 13')
SET @Option14Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 14')
SET @Option15Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 15')
SET @Option16Default = (SELECT SystemDefaultValue FROM Options WHERE [Description] = 'Option 16')

SELECT PYDC.Oid,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC1.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option1Default
    ELSE PYDCOC1.[Value]
    END AS Option1Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC2.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option2Default
    ELSE PYDCOC2.[Value]
    END AS Option2Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC3.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option3Default
    ELSE PYDCOC3.[Value]
    END AS Option3Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC4.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option4Default
    ELSE PYDCOC4.[Value]
    END AS Option4Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC5.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option5Default
    ELSE PYDCOC5.[Value]
    END AS Option5Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC6.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option6Default
    ELSE PYDCOC6.[Value]
    END AS Option6Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC7.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option7Default
    ELSE PYDCOC7.[Value]
    END AS Option7Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC8.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option8Default
    ELSE PYDCOC8.[Value]
    END AS Option8Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC9.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option9Default
    ELSE PYDCOC9.[Value]
    END AS Option9Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC10.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option10Default
    ELSE PYDCOC10.[Value]
    END AS Option10Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC11.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option11Default
    ELSE PYDCOC11.[Value]
    END AS Option11Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC12.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option12Default
    ELSE PYDCOC12.[Value]
    END AS Option12Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC13.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option13Default
    ELSE PYDCOC13.[Value]
    END AS Option13Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC14.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option14Default
    ELSE PYDCOC14.[Value]
    END AS Option14Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC15.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option15Default
    ELSE PYDCOC15.[Value]
    END AS Option15Value,
CASE
    WHEN PYDCOC16.[Value] IS NULL THEN @Option16Default
    ELSE PYDCOC16.[Value]
    END AS Option16Value
FROM ProductYearDistrictCrop PYDC   
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption1Values PYDCOC1
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC1.Oid --assuming that is the FK on ProductYearDistrictCropOption1Values that references ProductYearDistrictCrop.Oid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption2Values PYDCOC2
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC2.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption3Values PYDCOC3
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC3.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption4Values PYDCOC4
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC4.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption5Values PYDCOC5
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC5.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption6Values PYDCOC6
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC6.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption7Values PYDCOC7
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC7.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption8Values PYDCOC8
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC8.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption9Values PYDCOC9
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC9.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption10Values PYDCOC10
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC10.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption11Values PYDCOC11
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC11.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption12Values PYDCOC12
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC12.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption13Values PYDCOC13
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC13.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption14Values PYDCOC14
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC14.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption15Values PYDCOC15
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC15.Oid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductYearDistrictCropOption16Values PYDCOC16
        ON PYDC.Oid = PYDCOC16.Oid 
--WHERE Condition(s)
```

This version is:

1. Normalized and prevents you from adding a bunch of extra columns making `ProductYearDistrictCrop` wider
2. Allows you to only insert values where that particular `ProductYearDistrictCrop.Oid` is different than the default.  Which allows you to save a lot of space
3. Additional options only requires an additional `table` following the same format which is then supported with code updates in whatever `functions`/`queries`/`stored procedures`.

That is probably one of the harder ones to support when it comes to new options coming. It will also require the most amount of work in your initial development.  But a `VIEW` can probably be used to get around most of that.  However I think space and performance wise it will give a lot of benefits, which should be the primary priority when it comes to a database, particularly if you are already in a 2 Million row world with this one table.

Comment: I would argue that you could alleviate much of the EAV penalty by using a CTE and pivoting the set to flatten it for display purposes.  Do the same with the default value table.  With proper indexes it would be a single point of contact into each of the two tables.  For space saving, you could even have the EAV table not store a value if it matches the default.  This may prove problematical if the default values ever change, but making that a slowly changing dimension would be best for that in any case.  But space is cheap so it's early days to optimize that out.

Comment: @JonathanFite I think you are absolutely right.  The PIVOT command I have not spent a lot of time trying to understand so it didn't occur to me to use it.  I am not familiar with how well it performs in large table environments but it could certainly be used and probably make the EAV framework a very viable option.

Comment: @KirkSaunders fantastic reply! Thanks for taking the time to respond. It's clear that the EAV provides the most flexibility and is not a bad design choice given the requirements. (I usually try to avoid it at all costs)

Also, thanks for recommending the Extension Table as this is  a slightly better approach than just adding columns and is definitely part of my tool set now.

I think for this problem I will have to analyze what is most important for the client: Speed (Extension Table) or Flexibility (EAV).

Comment: @KirkSaunders

Just to add onto my previous comment: 

In my test scenarios the queries for EAV were pretty slow, but I suspect it can be optimized and will probably be future Stack Exchange posts.

For what it's worth you've shifted my opinion to the EAV approach, I just need to get the queries in a optimized state.

Comment: To answer the question about performance with PIVOT.  I think that with proper indexes it will perform fairly well.  And favorably compared to the large number of joins required for the other approach.  Fastest would be an "extension" table of some sort, but you lose a lot of flexibility with that approach as well.